# mingw compilers do not make exe after successful compilation

Tags: g++, fortran, mingw, gfortran

I have a strange problem with MinGw installation (on Win 8 PC). The compiler works for both fortran:

`gfortran hw.f -o hw.exe`

and for C++:

`g++ hwc.cpp -o hwc.exe`

However, **no** exe files are created. The compiler exits without option but there is just no EXE !?

When I make (intentionally) an error in the source, I have proper error message, so compiler
undoubtedly work. I tried using `-v` switch to see the flow and I see no suspicious messages as well.

So - what's the heck? :-)

Comment: post the messages from the `-v` flag

Answer (score 2):

Check "quarantined items" in your anti-virus software. I used to have similar problem with MinGW on XP+avast when I tried to build wxWidgets (2.8.x I think) - during the "configure" stage avast moved some (but not all) executables produced by configure script into "quarantined items folder".